# How to run replicas with different config settings

Tags: kubernetes

We have an application with 5 instances running the old fashioned way.
There are 5 directories on disk each with their own config settings.

Now we want to move these services into a kubernetes cluster, and have 5 replicas running each with their own settings but thats where I get stuck.

It's easy to get 5 identical replicas but for this the only thing I can come up with is 5x single selectors each with different secrets and configmaps defined. Is there a better way to create a deployment with 5x identical images with different configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ConfigMap for this:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serviceA
data:
  dir: |
    /var/log/svcA

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serviceB
data:
  dir: |
    /var/log/svcB
```

Then use the configmap as file from every pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: pod
    image: bla
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
  volumes:
  - name: vol
    configMap:
      name: serviceA
```

Comment: Beware that pods are low-level kubernetes building blocks. In most use cases Deployments or StatefulSets are better suited.

Comment: that is true, this works for kind: Deployment too